# partial html with vue js component in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, vue.js

I would like to render a partial html containing a vue js component and put it in a div with  ajax when i click on this div ,
the purpose of this is to create a messenger application with laravel (see the image example below)

[messenger app with laravel / vue js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBpVs.png)

The problem with this partials html , is that i have to put my app.js 
in each partials to render it in the final html page , otherwise it does not compile , so in final i have as many app.js as partials i have.. a lot of redundancy

Example of my components:

Send msg btn component :

```
<meta name="friendId" content="{{ $friend->id }}">
<chat-composer v-bind:userid="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" v-bind:chats="chats" v- 
bind:friendid="{{ $friend->id }}"></chat-composer>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

Chat conversation component :

```
 <audio id="ChatAudio" xmlns:v-bind="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <source src="{{ asset('sounds/chat.mp3') }}">
 </audio>
    <meta name="friendId" content="{{ $friend->id }}">
    <chat v-bind:chats="chats" v-bind:user="{{ Auth::user() }}"  v- 
 bind:friendname="{{$friend}}" v-bind:userid="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" v- 
 bind:friendid="{{ $friend->id }}"></chat>
```

Example of ajax code to render it :

```
        $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('messenger') }}' + '/'+ id,
        type: 'GET',
        //data: {id:id},
        success: function(data) {

            $('#showmessenger').html(data);


        }
```

Finally , Adding app.js in the final html page doest do the job , i have to put it in each partials ..

DO you have any solution , for partials to render without adding each time the app.js ?